# Laravel 5.6 $errors check form submitted?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a page containing a register form and login form. Both have similar variables being passed such as `email`, `password`, etc. So I need to know which form generated the error in Laravel 5.6. I'm sure this is trivial but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Thanks.

My code:

```
<!-- SIGN IN/UP FORM -->
        <div class="form-custom text-center container bg-white">
        @if(Session::has('message'))
            <div class="h1 text-success">
                {{ Session::get('message') }}
            </div>
        @endif

            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">

            <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
            <div class="tab-content mt-5">
                <div id="signin" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                    <!--SIGN IN-->
                    <form id="signin-form" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post" class="mb-3">
                       @csrf
                        <div class="container px-4">
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!--SIGN IN-->
                </div>

                <div id="signup" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <!--SIGN UP-->
                    <form id="signup-form" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post" class="mb-3">
                       @csrf
                        <div class="container px-4">
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <input type="hidden" name="account_type" value="3" required>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!--SIGN UP-->
                </div>

                <div id="filmmaker" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <!-- FILMMAKER -->
                    <form id="filmmaker-form" action="" method="post" class="mb-3">
                       @csrf
                        <div class="container px-4">
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
                            <input class="form-style" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <input type="hidden" name="account_type" value="2" required>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- FILMMAKER -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- TAB CONTENT -->

              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                 <li class="active">
                     <button data-toggle="pill" href="#signin" class="active btn btn-sign">Sign in</button>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <button data-toggle="pill" href="#signup" class="btn btn-sign">Sign up</button>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <h1 data-toggle="pill" href="#filmmaker" class="lead {{ $errors->any() ? 'filmmaker-error-text' : null }} filmmaker-custom mt-3">Are you a filmmaker?</h1>
                 </li>
             </ul>
            @if($errors->any() && old('login'))
                <div class="text-danger">Email and password combination is incorrect</div>
            @elseif($errors->any() && old('register'))
                <div class="text-danger">Please check your signup information</div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <!-- SIGN IN/UP FORM -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to prefix name of input according to signin or signup form. But I think you do not want do things this way, so try this

```
    <form action="signin" method="POST">

       <input type="email" name="email" />
       @if($errors->has('email') && old('mode') == 'signin'))
           {!! errors->first('email', '<span class="help-block'>:message</span>') !!}
       @endif
       <input type="password" name="password" />
       <input type="submit" name="mode" value="signin"/>
    </form>

    <form action="signup" method="POST">
       <input type="email" name="email" />
       @if($errors->has('email') && old('mode') == 'signup))
           {!! errors->first('email', '<span class="help-block'>:message</span>') !!}
       @endif
       <input type="password" name="password" />
       <input type="submit" name="mode" value="signup"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. In the `action` I put `{{ route('login') }}`. Could that possibly effect it? Also, I changed it to `@if($errors->any() && old('mode') == 'login')`.

Comment: Chaging `action` attribute did not effect it... If you want use $errors->any(), then do simply `@if(old('mode') == 'signin')` dont forget to name input:submit attribute name to login if you use `@if(old('mode') == 'login')`

Comment: It's still not working. I think I may start using different prefixes.